# No module named 'django_cas_ng'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a webpage using PyCharm, but when I run the server, I see  an error saying: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_cas_ng'.**

I looked up for solutions on sources like [this](https://github.com/mingchen/django-cas-ng/issues/71), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652452/using-django-cas-ng-to-authenticate-on-admin-site), and [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-cas-ng/3.1.0/). I believed I needed to install specific modules but none of them worked

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment first for running the server and did you install the package by `pip install django-cas-ng` before running the server?

Comment: @ruddra, yes I did. It is mentioned in one of the sources I stated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I used `pip install django-cas-ng` multiple times, but it did not go through. I restarted PyCharm and used the same line of code, it worked this time.